# How to read first 100 rows of a csv file in python appending comma, serial number and full stop marks?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, csv, reader

Suppose I am having 2 columns and 3000 rows in a .csv file. I want to read only the first 100 rows of the csv file, where i need to append a comma mark (`,`) after the first column and need to inject a full stop (`.`) to conclude the row. Is there any way to achieve the same. Also, I need to include the serial number before reading the first row. How to achieve this?

Input Format:

```
question              answer
what is your name     i am maxi
are you happy         yes i am
what you do           i am a student
```

Output:

```
1. what is your name, i am maxi.
2. are you happy, yes i am.
3. what you do, i am a student.
```

code which i have tried is as follows.

```
import csv
import itertools

with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
   mycsv = csv.reader(f)
   next(mycsv, None)
   for row in itertools.islice(mycsv, 100):
       row = ('"{}."'.format(', '.join(row)) for row in mycsv)

       raw_text = ', '.join(row)
       print(raw_text)
```

Comment: I would start with de-duplicating `row` you use it inside the for loop as well as inside the join statements for loop - this can get confusing.

Comment: And why do you iterage via islice over mycsv and also use it inside the for statement - that makes no sense?

Comment: Okay. Thanks Patrick I am trying and new to csv file  using python

Comment: look into `enumerate(iterable)` for your "serial number"

Comment: is your csv tabstop seperated?

Comment: @PatrickArtner. No its not tabstop separated.

Comment: Sorry, Patrick. I did not get your words rightly, as i told you i am absolutely new in it.

Comment: CSV = colon seperated values - your data HAS no colons in it. By what _identifier_ is your data seperated? Usually that is one of space, colon, semicolon, pipe or tabstop. Or you have a fixed width file where the 1st column is f.e. 20 chars wide, the second 10 chars wide etc. This has nothing to do with python at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194987/discussion-between-mishra-s-and-patrick-artner).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the crucial fields are separated by multiple spaces:

```
import re

with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    next(f)
    pat = re.compile(r'\s{2,}')

    for i, row in enumerate(f, 1):
        print('{}. {}.'.format(i, pat.sub(', ', row.strip(), 1)))
        if i == 100: break
```

Regex `\s{2,}` details:

- `\s` - whitespace character
- `{2,}` - *{n,m} where n >= 0 and m >= n*. Repeats the previous item between `n` and `m` times. Greedy, so repeating `m` times is tried before reducing the repetition to `n` times. Ex. `a{2,4}` matches `aaaa`, `aaa` or `aa`

Sample output:

```
1. what is your name, i am maxi.
2. are you happy, yes i am.
3. what you do, i am a student.
```

Comment: Thanks roman. I am not getting (,) after col 1 and not full stop (.) after column 2 for each 2. Rest all are okay.

Comment: @MishraS, ok ,fixed. See the update. If you're "not getting (,) after col 1" - then, you have different input text which differs from that you posted - cause I've used your text literally

Comment: Would you please explain me the `regex` which you have used.

Comment: @MishraS, yes, see the explanation

Answer (score 2):

A no regex variant of [RomanPerekhrest's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56610046/7505395):

**Create demo data:**

```
with open("data.csv","w") as f: 
    f.write(f"""question              answer
what is your name     i am maxi
are you happy         yes i am
what you do           i am a student
""") 
    for i in range(10): # 30some more lines
        f.write(f"""what is your name     i am maxi
are you happy         yes i am
what you do           i am a student
""")
```

**Process data:**

```
with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
    next(f) # skip header
    skipped = 0
    for number, line in enumerate(f,1):
        if line.strip():
            a,b = line.split("  ",1) # split at 2 spaces
            print(f"{number-skipped}. {a.strip()}, {b.strip()}.")
        else: 
            skipped += 1
        if number == 10: # reduced to 10 due to output lenght 
              break
```

**Output:**

```
1. what is your name, i am maxi.
2. are you happy, yes i am.
3. what you do, i am a student.
4. what is your name, i am maxi.
5. are you happy, yes i am.
6. what you do, i am a student.
7. what is your name, i am maxi.
8. are you happy, yes i am.
9. what you do, i am a student.
10. what is your name, i am maxi.
```

This should even handle empty lines in your data gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

Simple use pandas library:

```
import pandas as pd
# to load data from file
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
# test data
df = pd.DataFrame({"question": ['what is your name', 'are you happy', 'what you do '],
                   "answer": ["i am maxi", "yes i am", "i am a student"]})

# get fist 100 rows
df = df[:100]
# set numbers
df['number'] = np.arange(1,len(df)+1).astype(str)

df['summary'] = df['number'] + '. ' + df['question'] + ', ' + df['answer'] + '.'
```

Output:

```
            question          answer number                          summary
0  what is your name       i am maxi      1  1. what is your name, i am maxi.
1      are you happy        yes i am      2       2. are you happy, yes i am.
2       what you do   i am a student      3  3. what you do , i am a student.
```

Comment: Thanks Zaraki. How to define the `df` with `pd.DataFrame` if I have 1000 rows?

Comment: does not adress splitting at fixed width, does not provide the enumeration, does not use csv at all

Comment: @MishraS if You csv contains 2 columns then simply load data by using df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")